# codeigniter pagination with uri routing

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, routes

My controller is flex and my function name is **post_blog**. I have done the routing for this function `$config['blog'] = 'flex/post_blog'`. Till this everything is working fine. I added pagination for the page which is loaded by above function and my `$config['base_url'] = 'blog'`. Everything is fine on my first page but on the second page it is showing page not found.

How do I solve this problem?

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
        if($this->uri->segment(2)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ;
        }
        else{
        $page = 1;
        }


        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('blog');
        $config['total_rows'] = $post_count;
        $config['per_page'] = 15;
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current"><b>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $offset=(($page-1)*$config["per_page"]) ;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['links'] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
```

Comment: show code for pagination  `$config`

Comment: please check the code

Comment: Might be important.. none of the code after `echo $page; exit;` will be executed.. [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: i have removed the exit,that was for checking only

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('controller_name/blog');
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Also remove `echo $page;exit;`

Try Changing `$config['num_links'] = 2;` to `$config['num_links'] = $post_count;`

Comment: still showing not found . and i don't want controller name in the url